# Where do I see existing variables after executing my script?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, ide

Where do I see existing variables after executing my script? I have become accustomed to having a panel to see what existing variables I have and what their types and contents are in MATLAB and Spyder; how is this done in VSCode for Python?

Answer (score 1):

During debugging, you can inspect all available variables on the left side of the screen as shown in the following screenshot (although after debugging they disappear) [image: screenshot of debugging python code]

Comment: Note: you need to add a breakpoint to pause the program first before getting the above view

Comment: I am trying to use the 'Run Current File in Interactive Window' feature, but this leads to ipykernel needing and failing to install and I am struggling to learn what needs to be done. (e.g. I can't even install pip because despite choosing a 3.7 python environment the terminal appears to be in 2.7 mode even though i've reloaded it after choosing the 3.7 environment).

Comment: I usually just go to the debug tab (icon with a bug), click "Run and debug" and choose the "Python file: Debug the currently active Python file". As for the pip, I use the Miniconda for all python envs (and switching between them)